# Can't get PHP script to work, it shows up as a blank page

Tags: php, mysql, web

here is the code that creates a simple profile of a user with list of posts :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome ! </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
if(!$dbcon)
{
die('<p>'.'Unable to connect to database server'.mysql_error().'</p>');
}
?>

<?php
//select the database
mysql_select_db("rough_site",$dbcon);
//add the user 
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name'];
$user_password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_password'];
$user_mail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_mail'];
$adduser= "INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_password, user_mail) VALUES ($user_name, 
$user_password, $user_mail)";
$confirmUser = mysql_query($adduser);
if(!$confirmUser) 
{
die("Sorry , but you could not be added as a member of this site . ");
}
?>


<p align="center" ><h2><em>Latest posts by you </em></h2></p><br/>
<?php
// show the latest posts by this user 
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$latestposts = "SELECT post_id , post_title  from posts ,users where  
posts.user_name=users.$user_name " ;
$showlatestposts= mysql_query($latestposts);

?>

<blockquote>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($showlatestposts) )
{
echo '<p>'. '<a href = "showpost.php?post_id='. $row['post_id'].'">'.         
    $row['post_title'].'</a></p><br/>' ;
}
?>
</blockquote>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read your error logs and/or activate error reporting.

Comment: Have you turned on debugging? the blank page means there's an error, and I think it's from the multiline string you have used, that's not how it works for php

Comment: Not that it's the reason you're not seeing anything, but are you trying to insert a new record or update an existing one in your "INSERT INTO users set..." query?

Comment: [Sun Aug 07 10:49:24 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/expander/ADBMS/htdocs/profile.php on line 20, referer: http://127.0.0.1/htdocs/start.php
I don`t  undertsnad it.

Comment: @kinakuta I`m trying to insert records .

Comment: You should fix your query string. First, sanitize your input rather than inserting variable directly from $_POST into your query string: $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']); This helps you avoid SQL injection. Then, when you insert, you want your query to take the form of INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password, user_mail) VALUES ($user_name, $user_password, $user_mail) You use the set something = something when you're doing an UPDATE.

Comment: I updated the query tbut still a blank page .

Comment: @kinakuta mysql supports the insert set format, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Sure enough, you're right. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert value from array with named key to string, and to use `''` marks, you must enclose it in `{}` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing (Complex (curly) syntax)
So, for example,

```
$adduser= "INSERT INTO users set 
user_name=$_POST['user_name'],
user_password=$_POST['user_password'],
user_mail =$_POST['user_mail']";
```

must be

```
$adduser= "INSERT INTO users set 
user_name=\"{$_POST['user_name']}\",
user_password=\"{$_POST['user_password']}\",
user_mail =\"{$_POST['user_mail']}\"";
```

Comment: I get the die message of  'sorry could not be added" if i change the query to what you have given.

Comment: So, you have an error in SQL query now :) try `echo mysql_error();` or just enclose that data in `{}` brackets in additional `\"\"` as I edited

Comment: something is working :) ,but still I get this error :Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/expander/ADBMS/htdocs/profile.php on line 55  . I haven`t added any posts in the database .

Comment: Try adding `{}` brackets and `\"\"` to your `SELECT` statement to - may be parsed not correctly recognizes `$user_name` in `""`. So `$latestposts = "SELECT post_id , post_title  from posts ,users where  
posts.user_name=users.$user_name " ;` becomes `$latestposts = "SELECT post_id , post_title  from posts ,users where  
posts.user_name=\"{$user_name}\" " ;`

Comment: you sir saved me a few more hours of torture . Thank you :D .wish I could vote .

Answer (score 2):

Have you check your log file? Turn error_reporting(E_ALL) or maybe adding die(mysql_error()); in your queries... That might help to know what's wrong!

And if you do an INSERT INTO

It should be

INSERT INTO users VALUES (....) and not SET

SET is for an update

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html - Are you sure? `SET` is not only for updates!

Comment: see this link for insert set syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Wow haven't thought that SET was for an INSERT too... Anyway... Who is coding that way ?

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT query isnt in the correct syntax, and then you call the die() function, which would in turn result in a blank page.

Fix the query and you should be good.

### Update and the cause of your problem:

You have:

```
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name'];
$user_password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_password'];
$user_mail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_mail'];
```

And should be:

```
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$user_password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_password']);
$user_mail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_mail']);
```

You're not closing the function with the parentheses

Comment: die function should show the string he passed it, not a blank page.

Comment: I fixed the query but still blank page . other php files work correctly though :?

Comment: see this link for insert set syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Is the page blank your browser or does it output no html at all? Check the source code

Comment: @Joey, hi has a syntax error, he wrote about it in comments above

Comment: @user882440, I updated my answer. You often get that error when using double and single quotes together. Try it out.

And I found the missing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','On');
?>
```

I'm guessing that there's an error that you're not being told about, this will enable error reporting.

Comment: I added that in the body above all other php but I get a blank page . apache is working as I can see other php files :?

Answer (score 0):

in the browser if you go "view source" you might see the error text, it could be hidden from normal view due to invalid html

its probably the single quotes in here causing a syntax error.

```
$adduser= "INSERT INTO users set 
user_name=$_POST['user_name'],
user_password=$_POST['user_password'],
user_mail =$_POST['user_mail']";
```

try this instead (see the single quotes in the [ ] are removed, because the whole string is quoted it is not required

```
$adduser= "INSERT INTO users set 
user_name='$_POST[user_name]',
user_password='$_POST[user_password]',
user_mail = '$_POST[user_mail]'";
```

as others have recommended you should sanitize your sql parms
something like this

```
$user_name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$user_password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user_password']);
$user_mail = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user_mail']);

$adduser= "INSERT INTO users set 
user_name='$user_name',
user_password='$user_password',
user_mail = '$user_mail'";
```

Comment: i changed it but it doesn`t process the query . in browser on the error message of die function can be seen . no error or anything .

Comment: maybe try adding echo "got to step 1"; 2,3,4,5, etc trace messages in the code every so often and see what number gets echo'd up to. this will give you an idea of where the error is